# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/Icon')

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

This is my first attempt at Xamarin, just running through the examples at [Xamarin.com](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/).

But I'm getting this error when I try to build. It's strange because I can select the icon from the list on the properties tab but VS can't find them during the build.

I've tried moving the files so the path is really short.

I've tried adding new icons with differnt names and selecting them in the properties page.

Neither of these worked.

The AndroidManifest.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="Phoneword.Phoneword" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <!--suppress UsesMinSdkAttributes-->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="Phoneword" android:icon="@mipmap/Icon" android:name="android.app.Application" android:debuggable="true">
      <activity android:label="Phone Word" android:name="md5eb8cee9bb2852617ab2e56c7bf729ae8.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="Phoneword.Phoneword.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
      <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
      <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
          <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.Phoneword.Phoneword" />
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
    </application>
  </manifest>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a workaround. Go into assemblyinfo.cs (it's in the Properties folder in your project) and add the following line in there:

[assembly: Application(Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]

Comment: So, is it a bug?

Comment: Looks like there are a bunch of minor ommissions and out of date items in the Hello, Android: Quickstart

Answer (score 4):

The solution:

> 1. Change all "Icon.png" names into mipmap folders to "icon.png".
> 2. Clean project
> 3. Re-open Visual Studio
> 4. Select "@mipmap/icon" in "Application Icon" in AndroidManifest.

Comment: Can you explain why this will fix it? Thanks :)

Comment: This is the better solution because assets in the mipmap folder have to have names where all letters are in lower case. You cannot use hyphens either but you can use underscores. To make it more clear: `Icon` has a capital letter and its name is therefore forbidden in the mipmap folder.  Therefore, the solution is to rename it to `icon`. If you want a longer name, consider to use underscores, e.g. `my_company_icon`. Alternatively, put the icon with a capital letter in the drawable folder where capital letters are allowed! (but hypens are not alowed there either!)