# PhoneGap app did build; now errors

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

For some reason my PG app has stopped building. Literally nothing has changed - I simply tried to rebuild it. It used to work; now it doesn't.

The error is:

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>   aapt

Here's the relevant part of the log output:

> FAILED
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 0.985 secs
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output. Error: /project/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: Note:
>   Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile
>   with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   /project/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:25:23-35:
>   AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with
>   value '@mipmap/icon').
>        /project/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:22:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon'
>   with value '@mipmap/icon').
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>   aapt
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/project/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)

I've read other posts and tried some things suggested, but so far nothing is halping. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47085360/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-icon-with-value-mip) advised adding a line to the assemblyinfo.cs files, but I'm getting the same result.

I have no idea what most of the log output above means. Can anyone see what's going wrong!?

Comment: Are you using phonegap build? do you have a phonegap version set in the config.xml? which plugins are you using?

Comment: The only version mentioned in the config file, apart from the internal version I use to reference my app, is for the node `android-minSdkVersion`, and has a value of 14. The issue persisted after I removed all plugins via `cordova plugin rm {...}`. In the end I had to delete the app entirely, create a new skeleton app, install all the plugins again and then it worked. Not the first time I've gone to bed after a successful build, got up the next morning and the build fails! PG seems really unreliable in this regard, and the error messages are less than helpful unless you're a ninja.