# How do I run my first mobile app ("phoneword" demo) on my mobile phone with Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile, build

I've been trying to get the demo mobile app "phoneword" to work properly - I found a [question about an issue with @mipmap.png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47085360/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-icon-with-value-mip), but I'm still having trouble connecting to see it run on my phone. I've been able to successfully compile the app, and can connect with Visual Studio, but it almost immediately disconnects.

What do I need to do to see the app running on my phone? Do I need an active Azure account?

Comment: What problem/error do you meet? Do you mean you can't find your phone in `Debug Target` Option? Have you enabled `USB debugging` on your phone?

Comment: No, you don't necessary need an active Azure Account. Did you set the project you want to run/deploy to your phone as the startup project?